# Haskell powerset function - How to avoid Couldn't match expected type `IO t0' with actual type `[[Integer]]'

Tags: haskell

I have a powerset implementation that I'm trying to run here: http://rextester.com/runcode. I'm still getting this error and can't figure out how to make it right. I'm trying to read as much as possible about IO in haskell but it is super hard for me.

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)
powerset = filterM (const [True, False])

main =  powerset[1,2]
```

Comment: the problem is `main = ...` - see `main` has type `IO ()` - I think you want `main = print $ powerset [1,2]` instead

Comment: That solved the problem, thank You very much ! I have one more question, i want to be able to get input from standard input, how to make it as short as possible ?

Comment: see my answer - it's `getLine`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is `main = ...`

`main` should have type `IO ()` but you give an expression with type `[[Integer]]` (as the compiler tells you) - so as I think you want to output the result to the console I think you are looking for `print`

this works for me:

```
import Control.Monad (filterM)

powerset = filterM (const [True, False])

main =
  print $ powerset[1,2]
```

having said this you should add the top-level signatures:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (filterM)

powerset :: [a] -> [[a]]
powerset = filterM (const [True, False])

main :: IO ()
main =
  print $ (powerset [1,2] :: [[Int]])
```

#### additional question from comment

the usual way to get input from **stdin** is [`getLine :: IO String`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine)

Comment: I know i should do this, but I just want to make it as short as possbile with input from standard input and output

Comment: I don't even know **what** you want to do - so how should I answer this question?

Comment: maybe you are searching for `interact` ... but I just don't know

Comment: I want to make the shortest possible implementation of powerset function, with input from standard input, output where [] are changed to {}, and it should be able to run on this platform http://rextester.com/runcode.

Comment: so this is some kind of code-golf? In this case go with [subsequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:subsequences), `interact` ;) - I'm sure there are lots of even more clever and very short snippets out there but I'm not really good with this kind of stuff - I'm usually happy when it works and is more or less readable ;)

Comment: Yes, it is something as code-golf if my understanding what golf-code means is good. Subsequences is the answer i think ! In java there is a function replace() when i can replace every [ and ] with { and { }. Is there something simmialr in haskell ?

Comment: yes - for example: [replace](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgi-3001.2.2.2/docs/Network-CGI-Protocol.html#v:replace) - you can search for stuff like this using [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) or Hayoo ;)  - also note that a simple `map` should do too (but it might end up not very short)

Comment: Thank You very much for help, i know java and python only so functionall programming is something new to me but i start to like it a lot. !

Comment: `interact` is ... yucky.