# Replace all [ ] with {} - as short as possible

Tags: haskell

Given the code below:

```
import Data.List; 
main = (readLn :: IO [Integer]) >>= print . subsequences
```

It takes a list of integers from standard input (for example `[1,2,3]`) and outputs something like:

> `[[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`

I want it to be like this:

> `{},{1},{2},{1,2},{3},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}`

so my goal is to replace every `[` and `]` in the result string with `{` and `}` respectively.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What has the code you posted to do with the problem you're asking about?

Comment: I`m trying to learn haskell and i found that the best way to do it is to see how someone solve a problem.

Comment: But the problem you seem to be asking about has nothing to do with IO, nor with subsequences. So what is the point of that code snippet you posted? If you can't post any useful code attemps yet, please make the problem description exact by posting some example input and output.

Comment: @leftaroundabout ... AFAIK it's some kind of code-golf (see the discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30952309/haskell-powerset-function-how-to-avoid-couldnt-match-expected-type-io-t0-wi) - it's the last thing the OP still needs ;)

Comment: @leftaroundabout I`ve eddited the question so You can see what i mean.

Comment: So, you want the result of `"([1,2,3])"` to be `"{{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,2}"`, or what? I suppose not, but just tell use _what_ you want!

Comment: That is exactly what i want ! In the shortest possible version.

Comment: @Cosaquee I've edited your question to hopefully make it clearer. Can you confirm that that is what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that is excactly what i want to achive, thank You very much !

Comment: For the future, please try stuff like this yourself, preferrably not by writing entire programs where it's unclear what going on, but by fiddling around with functions in GHCi (it's really great for that kind of language-exploring). And first of all, it would probably be a good idea to [read a book on Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Books); I tend to recommend [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is love and to split `print` into `putStrLn . show` and then add a simple `map` in-between which does the conversion:

```
main :: IO ()
main = 
    let fn '[' = '{'
        fn ']' = '}'
        fn c   = c
    in (readLn :: IO [Integer]) >>= putStrLn . map fn . show . subsequences
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c3b4b7e5c9ed52f)

The above code, given `[1, 2, 3]`, will output:

> `{},{1},{2},{1,2},{3},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}}`

---

If this is a code golf, then you could have (**106 characters**):

```
f '[' = '{';f ']' = '}';f c = c;main = (readLn :: IO [Integer]) >>= putStrLn . map f . show . subsequences
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e27fbe81364a19cf)

Comment: Any way to make it shorter maybe ? I`m a little bit confused how to include reading from stdin now  ?

Comment: That is the best possible answer ! I wish it was shorter but still is super awesome, thank You !

Comment: @Cosaquee Shorter as in "less overall characters typed" or as in "shorter line"?

Comment: I think it's even shorter when you strip the signature and just move `fn` *outside* `main` (maybe [LambdaCase](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/LambdaCase)???)

Comment: @Carsten Only `case` has more cost than all three `f`s there. But yeah, if it's a code golf than moving `fn` out, calling it `f`, removing signatures and pushing everything together will make it shorter.

Comment: @Carsten less overall characters typed

Comment: If this is a code golf, you could have ``main=interact$map f.show.subsequences.(`asTypeOf`[0]).read;f '['='{';f ']'='}';f c=c`` (**84** chars)..